# JQuery- creating a table dynamically and adding a anchor tag is not showing anchor as link

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am newbie to Jquery.

I have an ajax call that fetches the data and links. I have to show that data in a dynamically created table.  In each table row, i would need to show the url with the anchor tag.

The problem i am facing is:

The add anchor tag is not showing as a link as the anchor tag is dynamically created and the links are not working.

```
   $('#jsp-data-header').append('<tr><th colspan="2">Functionalities of the Resource</th></tr>');
   $('<tr/>').appendTo($('#jsp-data-header'))
        .append($('<th/>').text('JSP files'))
        .append($('<td/>').text("<a href='"+tempurl+"'>"+tempurl+"</a>"));
```

How to make this appear as link and clicking on the link shouls take me to the url mentioned.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried `.html()` instead of `.text()` where you add the anchor?

Comment: @DevlshOne is right: http://jsfiddle.net/Tj3Mc/

Comment: +1 to @JasonSperske for fiddling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.append($('<td/>').html("<a href='"+tempurl+"'>"+tempurl+"</a>"));`

Answer (score 2):

Try this --

```
   $('#jsp-data-header').append('<tr><th colspan="2">Functionalities of the Resource</th></tr>');
   $('<tr/>').appendTo($('#jsp-data-header'))
        .append($('<th/>').text('JSP files'))
        .append($('<td/>').html("<a href='"+tempurl+"'>"+tempurl+"</a>"));
```

and here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj3Mc/), courtesy of Jason Sperske

Comment: And here is the pertinent section of the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2