# add <a> tag dynamically using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

index.html

```
<p class="feed-text" style="word-wrap:break-word;margin-top:10px;"><a href="/feeds/view/760">testing Ist part </a><a style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqveRU1eAmA" target="_blank">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqveRU1eAmA</a> testing 2nd part</p>
```

I want to add an `<a>` tag for "`testing 2nd part`" dynamically using java-script or iquery.

Is it possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817285/jquery-creating-a-table-dynamically-and-adding-a-anchor-tag-is-not-showing-anch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to wrap text:  http://jsfiddle.net/h9rxq/

```
$('p').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap(function(){
    return $('<a/>', {href: "anyURL"});
});
```

Comment: +1 - I was thinking `$($('p a:last').get(0).nextSibling).wrap('<a href="anyURL"></a>');`, but could never get a straight answer as to what the markup looked like.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in jQuery using `split` and `join` to find the text `testing 2nd part` in all `<p>` tags and replace them with `<a>testing 2nd part</a>`

```
$("p:contains('testing 2nd part')").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.split('testing 2nd part').join("<a>testing 2nd part</a>");
});
```

In your question you do not have a starting `<p>` tag add it like so:

```
<p>
  <a href="/feeds/view/760">testing Ist part </a>
  <a style="text-decoration:underline color:blue" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqveRU1eAmA" target="_blank">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqveRU1eAmA</a>
 testing 2nd part
</p>
```